# Having trouble adding fields to a SpringBoot entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection

Hello I am a beginner at SpringBoot and I am having trouble using Java reflection to validate my min and max fields. I have a Part class that with each part object having different min and max values for the inventory and I want to access those values at runtime in the validation part of my SpringBoot application.

This is the relevant code for the Part class:

```
@ValidInvRange
    int inv;

    int min;
    int max;
```

I want to know how I can access the integer values using reflection in a Validation class. I have been unable to figure it out so far.

So far I've tried for each value to this-

```
Field inv = Part.class.getDeclaredField("inv");
int inventory = (int) inv.get(inv);
```

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: You can use Hibernate Validator for the normal validation like above.

Comment: It throws an error about casting the inv field as an integer

Comment: Try changing the variable name "inv", seems to be present both in the local and in the class attribute.